# How to build up the observation array in Accord.NET using C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, k-means, accord.net

I'm trying to learn the ropes in Accord.NET and AI world...
The goal is clustering a list of Customers using the K-Means algorithm.
For each Customer, I got three features:

```
CustomerID, ProductCategory, TotQty, TotAmount

AAA, 01, 50, 3000
AAA, 02, 10, 150
BBB, 01, 45, 2700
...
```

Now, I have to pass the observations to K-Means algorithm:

```
double[][] observations = ... (?)

// Create a new K-Means algorithm
KMeans kmeans = new KMeans(k: 10);

// Compute and retrieve the data centroids
var clusters = kmeans.Learn(observations);

// Use the centroids to parition all the data
int[] labels = clusters.Decide(observations);
```

First Question: Do I have to group the data by Customer? Like this:

```
double[][] observation =
{                 
  new double[] { 1, 50, 3000,  2, 10, 150 },
  new double[] { 1, 45, 2700}
}
```

or:

```
double[][] observation =
{                 
  new double[] { 1, 50, 3000},
  new double[] { 2, 10, 150},
  new double[] { 1, 45, 2700}
}
```

Second Question: how I trace back the result to the original CustomerID?
I mean as soon as I got the result with the assigned Label `int[] labels = clusters.Decide(observations);` how I can determine which Customer belongs to which Cluster/Label?

Comment: 1) Probably - if your customers can be seen as individual observations, then yes, you can group them by customers - but do keep only the features that are different between each of them. 2) The output of the Decide method will be in the same order as the array of observations you have passed to it - so if the first customer was the first observation, the first output of the Decide function will be the label for the first customer. If you can, please post a short example of your data either here or in the issue tracker of Accord.NET and we can try to provide you with a working example! :-)

Comment: Thanks Cesar for your support! I will provide a sample data directly on Accord.NET issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

I made Generic K-means Library for c#

so you can use it for your second question. (After you got centroid you can get objects that belong to that centroid)

https://github.com/pashkovdenis/K-means/

Comment: I've taken a look at your code but: 1) it requires to fix the .sln (Solution) file, it seems to refer to an old version of VS, basically, I rebuilt it from scratch. 2) the Project doesn't use Accord.NET. I prefer to use Accord.NET way since it's a very wide spread solution with a strong community base. But anyway thank for you support